# How can Create Dynamic SQL for Column Names which are Quarter-End Dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have three tables that look like this.

```
--TABLE1
--DROP TABLE POR
CREATE TABLE POR
( IDRSSD varchar(10),
  Institution  VARCHAR(100),
  Filing_Type int)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53540', 'Wells', 3)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53550', 'BofA', 1)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53560', 'Chase', 2)
INSERT INTO POR
  (IDRSSD, Institution, Filing_Type)
VALUES
  ('53570', 'JPM', 4)

--TABLE2
--DROP TABLE RCA
CREATE TABLE RCA
( IDRSSD varchar(10),
  Schedule_Code  VARCHAR(10),
  Line_Item varchar(100),
  Code varchar(10),
  [2019Q4] varchar(10),
  [2019Q3] varchar(10),
  [2019Q2] varchar(10),
  [2019Q1] varchar(10),
  [2018Q4] varchar(10),
  [2018Q3] varchar(10))

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53540', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '127000', '146000', '9370', '1000', '1300', '12000')

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53540', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '4390', '8220', '7570', '9800', '11230', '15570')

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53560', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '14390', '8220', '700', '4800', '1230', '57')

INSERT INTO RCA
  (IDRSSD, Schedule_Code, Line_Item, Code, [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])
VALUES
  ('53560', 'RC', 'Cash & Noninterest-bearing Deps', 'RCFD1881',  '9000', '2200', '5700', '980', '300', '5570')

--TABLE3
--DROP TABLE Mapping
CREATE TABLE Mapping
( Schedule_Code varchar(10),
  Call_Report  VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO Mapping
(Schedule_Code, Call_Report)
VALUES
('RC', 'Balance Sheet')
INSERT INTO Mapping
(Schedule_Code, Call_Report)
VALUES
('RCA', 'Cash and Balances')
INSERT INTO Mapping
(Schedule_Code, Call_Report)
VALUES
('RCB', 'Securities')
```

Now, I can easily join the tables like this (child's play for you experts).

```
Select RCA.[IDRSSD],
       POR.Institution,
       POR.Filing_Type,
       RCA.Schedule_Code,
       Map.Call_Report,
       RCA.Line_Item,
       RCA.Code,
       Right(RCA.Code,4) As Harmonized_Code,
       RCA.[2019Q4],
       RCA.[2019Q3],
       RCA.[2019Q2],
       RCA.[2019Q1],
       RCA.[2018Q4],
       RCA.[2018Q3]
From [RCA] As RCA
INNER JOIN [POR] As POR
ON RCA.IDRSSD = POR.IDRSSD
INNER JOIN Mapping As Map
ON RCA.Schedule_Code = Map.Schedule_Code
```

Result:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What I want to do it try to pivot the quarter-end-dates dynamically, because the quarters will change from time to time (sometimes we will have more quarters and sometimes we will have less).  So, I would like the final result to look like this, if possible.

[![][2]][2]

Is this possible, or is it just too damn hard?

I tried this, and got a small pivot working, but it's not joining to the other two tables and it's not summing the amount.  Also, obviously my column names are not dynamic at all.

```
SELECT [IDRSSD], Qtr, Amt
FROM   
   (SELECT [IDRSSD], [2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3] 
   FROM RCA
   ) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Amt FOR Qtr IN   
      ([2019Q4], [2019Q3], [2019Q2], [2019Q1], [2018Q4], [2018Q3])  
)AS unpvt
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I tried this as well, and it didn't make a whole lot of progress.

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.[RCA]') 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
--print(@colsUnpivot)

set @query 
  = 'select *
     from [RCA]
     unpivot
     (
        data
        for d in ('''+ @colsunpivot +''')
     ) u'
print(@query)
```

Result:

```
select *
     from [RCA]
     unpivot
     (
        data
        for d in ('[IDRSSD],[Schedule_Code],[Code],[2019Q4],[2019Q3],[2019Q2],[2019Q1],[2018Q4],[2018Q3]')
     ) u
```

Comment: Have you tought about redoing the design so you store it in the table unpivoted (ie normalized)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the data using CROSS APPLY and apply aggregate as given below:

```sql
Select RCA.[IDRSSD],
       POR.Institution,
       POR.Filing_Type,
       RCA.Schedule_Code,
       Map.Call_Report,
       RCA.Line_Item,
       RCA.Code,
       Right(RCA.Code,4) As Harmonized_Code,
       Q.QuarterEnd, sum(cast(Q.Amount as int)) as Amount
From [RCA] As RCA
INNER JOIN [POR] As POR
ON RCA.IDRSSD = POR.IDRSSD
INNER JOIN Mapping As Map
ON RCA.Schedule_Code = Map.Schedule_Code
CROSS APPLY
(
VALUES
('2019Q4', RCA.[2019Q4]),
('2019Q3', RCA.[2019Q3]),
       ('2019Q2',RCA.[2019Q2]),
       ('2019Q1', RCA.[2019Q1]),
       ('2018Q4',RCA.[2018Q4]),
       ('2018Q3', RCA.[2018Q3])
) AS Q(QuarterEnd,Amount) 
GROUP BY RCA.[IDRSSD],POR.Institution, POR.Filing_Type,RCA.Schedule_Code,Call_Report, Line_Item,Code,QuarterEnd
```

Comment: I think this almost works!  I just updated my original post with my findings.

Comment: This works, I made a mistake on my end. Your code works.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  One more quick question, can I make the dates dynamic with this Cross Apply?  Something like: FROMDATE, TODATE...WHERE Quarter_End BETWEEN BETWEEN cast(floor(cast(fromDate as float)) as datetime)
                        AND cast(floor(cast(toDate as float)) as datetime)

Comment: @ASH, yes. you can have dynamic way of doing thing by having CROSS APPLY. You can have WHERE clause in the CROSS APPLY clause. You can pass value from outer query and add to WHERE clause in the CROSS APPLY clause.

Comment: How can I do that? I tried this: 

VALUES
('2019Q4',RCA.[2019Q4]),
('2019Q3',RCA.[2019Q3]),
('2019Q2',RCA.[2019Q2]),
('2019Q1',RCA.[2019Q1]),
('2018Q4',RCA.[2018Q4]),
('2018Q3',RCA.[2018Q3])
('2018Q2',RCA.[2018Q2])
) AS Q(QuarterEnd,Amount) 
Where Q.QuarterEnd>='2016Q1'

But when the dates are not in the table headers, I get an error. I was hoping to make it somewhat dynamic, so if the date is there grab it and if not, skip it.  Is that possible?

Comment: @ASH, Q.QuarterEnd>='2016Q1'  will not work, as it is a VARCHAR column. you need to have some think like YearQuarter combination '201601', '201602' like that and you can apply filter